# Need CRON Job Expression for trigger half a second

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I set cron job in Azure Web job. I read many blogs and articles for trigger web job every second.
But I did not find any expression for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because 1 second is the minimum time interval available.